# If $Y_t$ is an itô process, why $(dY_t)^2$ denote the Quadratic variation of $Y_t$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Let $$dY_t(\omega )=\mu(t,\omega )dt+\sigma (t,\omega )dB_t(\omega ).\tag{1}$$

Why exactly $(dY_t)^2$ is the quadratic variation of $dY_t$ ? At the end, what means exactly $dY_t$ for a process $Y_t$ ? Indeed, here $(1)$ is a notation for $$Y_t=Y_0+\int_0^t\mu(s,\cdot )ds+\int_0^t \sigma (s,\cdot )dB_s,$$

1) but avoiding $(1)$, what would be $dY_t$ in general ?

2) And also, what is $(dY_t)^2$ ? Why should it be a quadratic variation of the obscure process $dY_t$ ?

Comment: It's just notation. Don't worry too much about notation, if you can translate things into their rigorous form.

Comment: @Ian: Thanks, but how would you translate $(dY_t)^2$ into rigorous form ?

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what notation you're using, but I suspect that the intention is that $(dY_t)^2=\sigma(t,\omega)^2 dt$ so that $\int_0^t (dY_s)^2 $ is the quadratic variation up to time $t$. This has some relatively nice intuition in terms of Riemann sums: heuristically $(dt)^2=0,dt dB_t=0,(dB_t)^2=dt$, which can be justified by writing out the corresponding Riemann sums that would ostensibly define integrals with respect to differentials that look like that (e.g. $\int_0^1 f(x) (dx)^2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(kh/n) (\Delta x)^2$.)